# How to get values in show action in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have access to the parameters in nested attributes..... Below is the code.

```
<%= link_to "Invoice", user_invoice_path(@user, invoice) %>
```

How do I access the user and invoice in the Invoice controller show action.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end
```

Invoice Model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I know how it works when it is not nested.... Can anyone, please help?

Comment: Not sure what you need but did you try params[:user][:invoice]

Comment: Is a user model involved or are the parameters themselves nested?

Comment: The user model has invoices....

Comment: Please specify the rails version, as that will affect your controller (ie. strong params)

Comment: @HunterStevens - I am not sure `strong params` related to find the objects other than object creation.

Comment: @VenkatCh nevertheless, OP should identify his version of Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can't find the `@user` or `@invoice` in this way.

Please debug your `show` action and you will find `params` as follows,

`{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"invoices", "user_id"=>"307", "id"=>"359"}`

So now write your show action something like,

```
def show
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

There may be better ways to find the objects in the controller action. But this is the basic approach you will have to consider instead of what you tried.